# Formatting DataRow.Item throws System.InvalidCastException - why?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, formatting

VS 2022 Community 17.5.3, Console App.
The last Console.WriteLine in the following throws an InvalidCastException.

```
Module Module1
   Dim DT1 As DataTable = New DataTable("DT1")

   ' Add a column to the DataTable
   Dim FieldType As Type = GetType(System.Int64)
   Dim MyColumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn("Col1", FieldType)
   DT1.Columns.Add(MyColumn)

   ' Add a Row to the DataTable and populate it
   Dim NewRow As DataRow = DT1.NewRow
   Dim RowArray() As Object = New Object() {1234}
   NewRow.ItemArray = RowArray
   DT1.Rows.Add(NewRow)

   ' Display formatted value from Row, Col1
   Console.WriteLine("Col1 Value = " & NewRow.Item("Col1"))
   Console.WriteLine("Col1 Type = " & NewRow.Item("Col1").GetType.ToString)
   Console.WriteLine("Col1 Formatted Value = " & NewRow.Item("Col1").ToString("N0"))

End Sub
```

Output is:
Col1 Value = 1234
Col1 Type = System.Int64

Then, the debugger kicks in with:

```
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Conversion from string "N0" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualBasic
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value) in f:\dd\vb\runtime\msvbalib\Helpers\Conversions.vb:line 788
   at ConsoleTest.Module1.Main() in C:\Data\VB.NET\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest\Module1.vb:line 1434

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo) in Conversions.vb
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String) in Conversions.vb
    Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String) in Conversions.vb

Inner Exception 1:
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Why can't I use ("N0") as the ToString format option? The column has a DataType of Int64 but converting it to a String (ToString) seems to be treating the format text ("N0") as an index of an array instead of a format code.

If instead of the the line:

```
    Console.WriteLine("Col1 Formatted Value = " & NewRow.Item("Col1").ToString("N0"))
```

I use:

```
    Dim MyInt64 As Int64 = NewRow.Item("Col1")
    Console.WriteLine("Col1 Value Formatted = " & MyInt64.ToString("N0"))
```

I get the desired and expected result:
Col1 Formatted Value = 1,234

Comment: I'd recommend to compile with `Option Strict On`.  This looks likely to be a dynamic type vs static type problem.  That is, the *dynamic* type of `NewRow.Item("Col1")` may be `Int64`, but the *static* type is likely to be something else.  Without `Option Strict`, VB can perform late-binding, but I believe it will still prefer to perform early binding when possible---and without `Option Strict`, it may be happy to bind to a `ToString` overload that takes an integer parameter even when the provided parameter is a string.

Comment: `NewRow.Item("Col1")` is an object, not an integer. If you're sure it will be an integer, you could use `Integer.Parse(NewRow.Item("Col1")).ToString("N0")`. At least I think so. You may want to use `TryParse` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously have `Option Strict Off` if this works:

```vb
Dim MyInt64 As Int64 = NewRow.Item("Col1")
```

The `DataRow.Item` property is type `Object` so that code is relying on an implicit narrowing conversion from `Object` to `Long`, which is not allowed with `Option Strict On`. This is an example of why you should ALWAYS have `Option Strict On`. It forces you to be explicit with your typing so there can be no confusion. As it is, you are relying on the system to guess what you mean to do and, while it will get it right most of the time, sometimes it will get it wrong. This is one of those times. Here:

```vb
Dim MyInt64 As Int64 = NewRow.Item("Col1")
Console.WriteLine("Col1 Value Formatted = " & MyInt64.ToString("N0"))
```

you're calling `ToString` on a `Long` value so the system knows exactly what overload you want to call. Here:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("Col1 Formatted Value = " & NewRow.Item("Col1").ToString("N0"))
```

the system actually thinks that you're calling the `Object.ToString` method with no parameters and then indexing the resulting `String` to get the `Char` at that index. Because VB allows you to omit the empty parnetheses on a call to a method with no parameters, it's interpreting that code as this:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("Col1 Formatted Value = " & NewRow.Item("Col1").ToString()("N0"))
```

which is the same as this:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("Col1 Formatted Value = " & NewRow.Item("Col1").ToString().Chars("N0"))
```

That `Chars` property is expecting a `Integer` index but the `String` "N0" cannot be converted to an `Integer`, so that's what the error message is telling you. Because you have `Option Strict Off`, none of that check doesn't occur until run time, instead of being caught at compile time.

The solution is to ALWAYS have `Option Strict On` and be explicit with your typing. You can turn it `On` in the project properties and you should also turn it `On` in the VS options, so it will be `On` by default for all future projects. Once it's `On`, you'll probably get a lot of errors where your code relies on implicit conversions and late binding, so you'll have to fix each one with an appropriate cast or conversion.

The specific solution here is to actually get a `Long` value from the `DataRow` and then you can call that overload of `ToString`. There are various ways to do that but I would do this:

```vb
Console.WriteLine($"Col1 Formatted Value = {NewRow.Field(Of Long)("Col1"):N0}")
```

That uses string interpolation to clean things up a bit, which means no need to call `ToString` directly anyway. That `Field` method is part of LINQ to DataSet and allows you to get a field value as a specific type. Note that you could also use the composite formatting built right into `Console.WriteLine`:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("Col1 Formatted Value = {0:N0}", NewRow.Field(Of Long)("Col1"))
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered that it would parse it as a no-argument call to ToString followed by an indexer.  Yikes!

Comment: I do have Option Strict Off (and probably have it off in every project - yikes!) When I turn Option Strict On, I do get an error indicating a problem converting String to Integer. I will most likely use Option Strict On everywhere (eventually). BUT, the real question becomes how does specifying that the column DataType is Int64 ever help me? I mean I am telling the DataColumn that it is Int64, but it seems to be handling it as just an Object. And one last thing - where do I find out the difference between static and dynamic data types assuming that applies here?

Comment: @BandannaMan, a `DataTable` works pretty much like a database table. The columns describe the data and the rows contain the data. Each field in a `DataRow` has to be type `Object` because it has to be able to store any type of object. If you just grab data from the row then you get an `Object` reference and that's it. If you want to use it as its actual type then it's up to you to know or find out what that type is from the column and then do as appropriate...

Comment: ...If, for instance, you bind a `DataTable` to a `DataGridView`, the column data types are used to decide what types of columns to add to the grid. Those data types are also use to validate any input from the user. That's all code written by someone at Microsoft doing that. It doesn't just happen on its own. If you want similar behaviour in your own code, you have to write it...

Comment: ...Basically, you should be aware that everything that comes out of a `DataTable` is an object and perform all the appropriate casts yourself when you get the data. If you need to use a value from a row field as type `Long` then cast as type `Long`, just as you would in any other code. `Option Strict On` will force you to do that by preventing you using methods of any other type on a reference of type `Object`. That is late binding and it's not allowed with `Option Strict On`. It's something that VB developers have got used to using, even if it's not required, and that's a bad thing...

Comment: ...There are no static and dynamic types. There's early binding, i.e. using a reference/value of a particular type to invoke members of that type, and there's late binding, i.e. using an `Object` reference to invoke members of the type the object will be a run time. Late binding was used, often unnecessarily, a lot in VB6 and earlier, so Microsoft allowed it by default in VB.NET so as not to break upgraded code. ALL VB.NET developers should immediately turn `Option Strict On` at the project level and only turn it `Off` at the file level where it's required, e.g. for Office Automation.

Comment: OK, great. The term static/dynamic types threw me a bit, but I understand (a bit) early/late binding. And I am learning that the only advantage of setting the DataColumn.DataType is that it can be used as a reference later for casting the objects to their correct types. In any case, THANK YOU, to all who responded to my dilemma - I really appreciate it.

Comment: @BandannaMan, if this answer has addressed your issue, please accept it by clicking the check mark. That way, everyone can see that you no longer need help without opening the question.

Comment: If you don't like "static" and "dynamic", I guess you can use different words (I might suggest "compile-time" and "run-time"), but I intended to be complementary to early binding and late binding.  Early binding is based on the compile-time type, late binding is based on the run-time type.  Of particular note is that even when late binding is enabled, it is still a fallback, and the compiler will early bind if it can even if there would be a "better" match in late binding.